# npm ERR! While resolving: @material-ui/core@4.12.4

Tags: npm, material-ui, npm-install, npm-package

While deploying a React app to **Azure App Service** we are getting this error, this was working absolutely fine till yesterday, we don't have any new updates to **package.config**

```
3:58:19 PM envoy-beta: Running 'npm install'...
3:58:25 PM envoy-beta: npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
3:58:25 PM envoy-beta: npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
3:58:25 PM envoy-beta: npm ERR! 
3:58:25 PM envoy-beta: npm ERR! While resolving: @material-ui/core@4.12.4
3:58:25 PM envoy-beta: npm ERR! Found: @types/react@18.0.21
3:58:25 PM envoy-beta: npm ERR! node_modules/@types/react
3:58:25 PM envoy-beta: npm ERR!   @types/react@"^18.0.8" from the root project
3:58:25 PM envoy-beta: npm ERR!   peerOptional @types/react@"*" from @material-ui/types@5.1.0
3:58:25 PM envoy-beta: npm ERR!   node_modules/@material-ui/types
3:58:25 PM envoy-beta: npm ERR!     @material-ui/types@"5.1.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4
3:58:25 PM envoy-beta: npm ERR!     node_modules/@material-ui/core
3:58:25 PM envoy-beta: npm ERR!       @material-ui/core@"^4.12.4" from the root project
3:58:25 PM envoy-beta: npm ERR!       1 more (@material-ui/lab)
3:58:25 PM envoy-beta: npm ERR!     @material-ui/types@"5.1.0" from @material-ui/styles@4.11.5
3:58:25 PM envoy-beta: npm ERR!     node_modules/@material-ui/styles
3:58:25 PM envoy-beta: npm ERR!       @material-ui/styles@"^4.11.5" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4
3:58:25 PM envoy-beta: npm ERR!       node_modules/@material-ui/core
3:58:25 PM envoy-beta: npm ERR!         @material-ui/core@"^4.12.4" from the root project
3:58:25 PM envoy-beta: npm ERR!         1 more (@material-ui/lab)
3:58:25 PM envoy-beta: npm ERR!   14 more (@mui/base, @mui/icons-material, @mui/lab, @mui/material, ...)
3:58:25 PM envoy-beta: npm ERR! 
3:58:25 PM envoy-beta: npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
3:58:25 PM envoy-beta: npm ERR! peerOptional @types/react@"^16.8.6 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4
3:58:25 PM envoy-beta: npm ERR! node_modules/@material-ui/core
3:58:25 PM envoy-beta: npm ERR!   @material-ui/core@"^4.12.4" from the root project
3:58:25 PM envoy-beta: npm ERR!   peer @material-ui/core@"^4.12.1" from @material-ui/lab@4.0.0-alpha.61
3:58:25 PM envoy-beta: npm ERR!   node_modules/@material-ui/lab
3:58:25 PM envoy-beta: npm ERR!     @material-ui/lab@"^4.0.0-alpha.61" from the root project
```

> What is already tried

1. npm install --legacy-peer-deps
2. npm install --legacy-peer-deps --force
3. npm install --force
4. We deleted node_modules completely and have installed them again

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you installed @types/react version 18 not supported in material-ui version 4.
So you have to downgrade @types/react v17 or upgrade material ui version 5.

https://dev.to/ifeanyichima/how-to-downgrade-from-react-18-to-1702-818

Comment: Appreciate you answer , but this didn't help fix the issue , i tried both the ways , i first tried to upgrade MUI version to 5 , when that didn't work , i reverted the changes and tried downgrade React to 17 from 18